# Loading XML file into database (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, database

I'm using Ruby on Rails for a website. I want to load external (cross-domain) XML files into this application, and store them in a database. The reason why I want to do this, is because There are several XML files the user can 'pick', so loading them on request is going to make the site very slow. So, I want to load the XML files into the database every 5 minutes or so, and let the user select things from the database. I would like to hear your opinions on this subject, and what you think is the best way to go about this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to load XML files whenever needed.Because if you load XML file for every 5 minutes your application will become very slow.

You can also use the background job gems for loading XML file into the database so that it will reduce your application burden.

Some of the background job gems.

[Delayed job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job)

[Backgroundrb](https://github.com/gnufied/backgroundrb)

[Spawn](https://github.com/tra/spawn)